# ASA5505, 9.1, Static NAT Port Range Forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, cisco-asa

ASA5505 Version 8.4+  (Using 9.1)..

Adding port range for static nat.

```
object network server_x
 host 123.123.123.123

access-list outside_in extended permit tcp any object server_x range 1000 2000

object network server_x
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp range 1000 2000??
```

.... I'm kind of lost at the static nat part.  how do I static nat a port range?

#### UPDATE #1

I'm still trying to solve this and am having a hard time, I have like 1000 ports to forward for phone system teleworker VoIP phones and I can't do them one port at a time, the ASA5505 config would be huge!

#### UPDATE #2

I can't do 1:1 Static Nat and then define the range in the access-list.  I use the same external IP for many services on different IP address on the inside network.

Comment: Same problem here :(